# Rails: An elegant way to display a message when there are no elements in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, iterator

I realized that I'm writing a lot of code similar to this one:

```
<% unless @messages.blank? %>
  <% @messages.each do |message|  %>
    <%# code or partial to display the message %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  You have no messages.
<% end %>
```

Is there any construct in Ruby and/or Rails that would let me skip that
first condition? So that would be executed when iterator/loop won't enter even once? For
example:

```
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
  <%# code or partial to display the message %>
<% and_if_it_was_blank %>
  You have no messages.
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you use the `:collection` parameter to render e.g. `render :partial => 'message', :collection => @messages` then the call to render will return `nil` if the collection is empty. This can then be incorporated into an || expression e.g.

```
<%= render(:partial => 'message', :collection => @messages) || 'You have no messages' %>
```

In case you haven't come across it before, render `:collection` renders a collection using the same partial for each element, making each element of `@messages` available through the local variable `message` as it builds up the complete response. You can also specify a divider to be rendered in between each element using `:spacer_template => "message_divider"`

Comment: great... how about a before collection and after collection? 
say you want to have <ul> and </ul> or <tr></tr> tag pairs before and after the partial rendering but only if the @messages ar enot empty. 

examples- > <p><ul><li>message1</li><message2></ul><p> is @messages!=nil OR <p><ul>no messages!<p>

Comment: I think that Fernando Allen's solution should be added to this answer as possible alternative, as people might skip it because it's not the "best answer".

Comment: just a quick note that may be helpful. in order for this syntax to work, you must use parentheses around the `partial` assignment as shown above. without them, the partial renders correctly, but the conditional message does not

Answer (score 167):

You could also write something like this:

```
<% if @messages.each do |message| %>
  <%# code or partial to display the message %>
<% end.empty? %>
  You have no messages.
<% end %>
```

Comment: How would you do something like this in haml/slim?

Comment: Thanks!  The accepted answer is more Rails-y (and probably should be the accepted answer for exactly that reason), but this one is going to save me a lot of time while I build a prototype.

Comment: What is this feature called?

Answer (score 18):

I'm surprised my favorite answer isn't up here.  There is an answer thats close, but I don't like bare text and using content_for is klunky.  Try this one on for size:

```
  <%= render(@user.recipes) || content_tag("p") do %>
    This user hasn't added any recipes yet!
  <% end %>
```

Comment: This is my favourite answer so far.

Comment: **Important:** don't forget parentheses for `render`, otherwise the `||` will apply not to the result of `render`, but to the collection itself. I've just written the same myself, but it didn't work (at first) because of this.

Comment: This was the elegant solution I was looking for :)

Answer (score 17):

One way is to do something like:

```
<%= render(:partial => @messages) || render('no_messages') %>
```

Edit:

If I remember correctly this was made possible by this commit:

http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a8ece12fe2ac7838407954453e0d31af6186a5db

Answer (score 6):

You can create some custom helper. The following one is just an example.

```
# application_helper.html.erb
def unless_empty(collection, message = "You have no messages", &block)
  if collection.empty?
    concat(message)
  else
    concat(capture(&block))
  end
end

# view.html.erb
<% unless_empty @messages do %>
  <%# code or partial to dispaly the message %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

As a note, you may as well just iterate over an empty array if you're looking for efficiency of expression:

```
<% @messages.each do |message|  %>
  <%# code or partial to dispaly the message %>
<% end %>
<% if (@messages.blank?) %>
  You have no messages.
<% end %>
```

While this does not handle @messages being nil, it should work for most situations. Introducing irregular extensions to what should be a routine view is probably complicating an otherwise simple thing.

What might be a better approach is to define a partial and a helper to render "empty" sections if these are reasonably complex:

```
<% render_each(:message) do |message|  %>
  <%# code or partial to dispaly the message %>
<% end %>

# common/empty/_messages.erb
You have no messages.
```

Where you might define this as:

```
def render_each(item, &block)
  plural = "#{item.to_s.pluralize}"
  items = instance_variable_get("@#{plural}")
  if (items.blank?)
    render(:partial => "common/empty/#{plural}")
  else
    items.each(&block)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Old topic but I didn't really like any of these so playing around on Rails 3.2 I figured out this alternative:

```
<% content_for :no_messages do %>
  <p>
    <strong>No Messages Found</strong>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= render @messages || content_for(:no_messages) %>
```

Or if  you need a more verbose render with partial path like I did:

```
<%= render(:partial => 'messages', 
     :collection => @user.messages) || content_for(:no_messages) %>
```

This way you can style the "no messages" part with whatever HTML / view logic you want and keep it nice a easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

That code can be shortened to:

```
<%= @messages.empty? ? 'You have no messages.' : @messages.collect { |msg| formatted_msg(msg) }.join(msg_delimiter) %>
```

Comments:

formatted_msg() - helper method which adds formatting to the message

msg_delimiter - variable containing delimiter like "\n" or "`<br />`"

BTW I'd suggest to use empty? method instead of blank? for checking an array, because a) its name is more concise :) and b) blank? is an ActiveSupport extension method which won't work outside Rails.

Comment: Thanks for suggesion but I prefer to use blank? because i don't have to check if object is not nil, and being only rails specific extension doesn't bother me much in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could split up your two cases into different templates: one if messages exist and one if no message exist. In the controller action (`MessagesController#index` probably), add as the last statement:

```
render :action => 'index_empty' if @messages.blank?
```

If there are no messages, it'll display `app/views/messages/index_empty.html.erb`. If there are messages, it'll fall through and display `app/views/messages/index.html.erb` as usual.

If you need this in more than just one action, you can nicely refactor it into a helper method like the following (untested):

```
def render_action_or_empty (collection, options = {})
    template = params[:template] || "#{params[:controller]}/#{params[:action]}"
    template << '_empty' if collection.blank?
    render options.reverse_merge { :template => template }
end
```

With this, you just need to put `render_action_or_empty(@var)` at the end of any controller action and it'll display either the 'action' template or the 'action_empty' template if your collection is empty. It should also be easy to make this work with partials instead of action templates.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution works for me because I want `tr` and `td` with `colspan` property:

```
<%= render(@audit_logs) || content_tag(:tr, content_tag(:td, 'No records',colspan: "11"))%>
```